# Action on detection of object

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, automation, computer-vision

Today I successfully build a custom object detection system using tensorflow (deep learning) and cv2.

Now for the next step, I want to implement an Action(or trigger) like if this object is detected then do this.

example: if a baseball bat is detected then print "let's try to make a home run"

Actually, after a particular object is detected then I want to send a message to my android app using google firebase.

```
# coding: utf-8

# # Object Detection Demo
# Welcome to the object detection inference walkthrough!  This notebook will                         
walk you step by step through the process of using a pre-trained model to 
detect objects in an image. Make sure to follow the [installation 
instructions]        
# # Imports
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


# ## Env setup
# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")
sys.path.append("D:\work\O_detection\models")
sys.path.append("D:\work\O_detection\models\slim")

# ## Object detection imports
# Here are the imports from the object detection module.
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

# # Model preparation
# ## Variables 
# Any model exported using the `export_inference_graph.py` tool can be loaded here simply by changing `PATH_TO_CKPT` to point to a new .pb file.  
# By default we use an "SSD with Mobilenet" model here. See the [detection model zoo]                
# What model to download. / load from memory
MODEL_NAME = 'gun_detection_graph'
#MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
#DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('training', 'object-detection.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 1

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

# ## Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map,         
max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


# ## Helper code
def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


# # Detection
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:

      ret,image_np = cap.read()

      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run([boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(image_np, np.squeeze(boxes),np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),np.squeeze(scores),category_index,use_normalized_coordinates=True,line_thickness=8)

      cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np,(800,600)))
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          cv2.destroyAllWindows()
          break
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to interface firebase from within your python script. Have a look at this interface. https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase

Comment: This is a link only answer that has only merit as long as the link exists. Please flesh out your answer so that is is stand-alone, and can help solve this problem even if the link is down.